# JS array returning element at index i+1 instead of index i element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I’m learning JavaScript and I want to implement Gale Shapley algorithm, not exactly that but something similar. A Player orders his choices between available choices and each Choice choose the best ranked players according to the limit of it’s place. Then the rest of players loose their first choices and their second choice become their first one, and the process restart.

```
class Player {
  constructor(email, choices, rank) {
    this.email = email;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.rank = rank;
  }
}
class Choice {
  constructor(name, places) {
    this.name = name;
    this.places = places;
  }
}
class FinalList {
  constructor(email, choiceObtained) {
    this.email = email;
    this.choiceObtained = choiceObtained;
  }
}
var Players = [
  new Player("alex1@mail.com", ["asr", "abd", "gl"], 3),
  new Player("alex2@mail.com", ["abd", "gl", "asr"], 1),
  new Player("alex3@mail.com", ["gl", "abd", "asr"], 4),
  new Player("alex4@mail.com", ["abd", "asr", "gl", 2]),
  new Player("alex5@mail.com", ["gl", "asr", "abd"], 5),
  new Player("alex6@mail.com", ["gl", "asr", "abd"], 7),
  new Player("alex7@mail.com", ["asr", "gl", "abd"], 9),
  new Player("alex8@mail.com", ["asr", "abd", "gl"], 6),
  new Player("alex9@mail.com", ["abd", "gl", "asr"], 8),
  new Player("alex10@mail.com", ["asr", "gl", "abd"], 10),
];
var AvailableChoices = [
  new Choice("abd", 4),
  new Choice("asr", 4),
  new Choice("gl", 2),
];

function algorithm(players, availableChoices) {
  var temp = [];
  var list = [];

  function doSort() {
    for (let i = 0; i < availableChoices.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
        console.log("-Before :");
        if (availableChoices[i].name.localeCompare(players[j].choices[0])) {
          temp.push(new FinalList(players[j].email, players[j].choices[0]));
          console.log(
            availableChoices[i].name +
              "---" +
              players[j].email +
              "___" +
              players[j].choices[0]
          );
          console.log(temp);
        }
      }

      if (temp.length > availableChoices[i].places) {
        temp.sort((et1, et2) => {
          return et1.rank - et2.rank;
        });
        temp.splice(temp.length, temp.length - availableChoices[i].places);
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        list.push(new FinalList(temp[i].email, temp[i].choices[0]));
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        players.splice(temp.indexOf(temp[i].email, 1));
      }
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    players[i].choices.shift();
  }
  doSort();

  return list;
}

console.log(algorithm(Players, AvailableChoices));
```

In the block

```
if (availableChoices[i].name.localeCompare(players[j].choices[0])) {
      temp.push(new FinalList(players[j].email, players[j].choices[0]));
         console.log(availableChoices[i].name +"---" +
                  players[j].email +
                  "___" +
                  players[j].choices[0]
              );
          console.log(temp);
}
```

the console output for `players[j].choices[0]` shows the `players[j].choices[1]` instead. And it makes that I’m getting the wrong Final list. And Surely, it’s not the only error in my code. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `algorithm` function, you run this loop, just before you call `doSort()`

```
for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    players[i].choices.shift();
}
```

If you didn't know, [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first item in an array, shifts the index of the other items and returns the removed item.

In the `doSort` function is where you try to print this

...

```
console.log(
 availableChoices[i].name + 
 "---" +
 players[j].email +
 "___" +
 players[j].choices[0]
);

...
```

And before the function is even called, the first item of the array (`player[j].choices`) you expect has already been removed.